# React, this.props is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this is a very common problem and I looked into many other complaints before posting this.

I have class Parent

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      ...
    };

  }
  ....

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={materialTheme}>
        <Child 
          ref={...} 
          groupId={this.state.groupId}
          groupUniqueId={this.state.groupUniqueId} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

And a class Child

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      ...
    };
    ...
  }
  getUsers() { 
    const url = `/someurl/${this.props.groupId}`;
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (...);
  }
}

export default Child;
```

However, in the class Child, I get an error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined"

Is there something obvious that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: constructor(props) { super(props)....

Comment: pass the props in the constructor as well. like this
```constructor(props) { super(props)...}```

Comment: Thanks, Yossi and Usama Tahir. That fixed it. Should have looked better into it :/

Comment: child class is in same component yeah in another component

Comment: add super(props) for parent component instead of just super()

Comment: For future reference, you should supply the entire stack trace and reference what line in your code causes the error.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because your `this` is not referencing a class. It is referring to your function. You can either use arrow functions or bind this to your function in constructor. Just add below line

```
constructor() {
super(props);
  this.state = { 
    ...
  }
   this.getUsers = this.getUsers.bind(this)
 }
```